# validate form php 4 inputs, one must be filled

Tags: php

I have a form which I need to fill in one field. I am trying but not having any success.

Please point to me where I am doing it wrong.

```
if($text1=='' && $text2=='' && ($text3!='' || $text4!='' || $text5!='' || $text6!='')){

                    $abc->redirect('../xxxx.php');  
                    exit;

                    }


<tr>
<td>title: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="dailyprice" name="text1" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
<td>Desc: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="weeklyprice" name="text2" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Daily Price: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="dailyprice" name="text3" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
<td>Weekly Price: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="weeklyprice" name="text4" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Weekend Price: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="weekendprice" name="text5" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
<td>Monthly Price: $</td>
<td><input type="text" id="monthlyprice" name="text6" style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: "not successful" is not an explanation of the issue

Comment: Are you saying just one field needs to be filled or all fields?

Comment: text1 or text2 must filled OR (text3 text4 text5 and text6) one must filled

Comment: So either text1 and text2 need to be filled or only one of (text3 text4 text5 and text6) needs to be filled. Am I correct?

Comment: Since you seem new to the English language, try writing it in boolean algebra to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then try something like this.

```
if ((empty($text1) && empty($text2)) || (empty($text3) && empty($text4) && empty($text5) && empty($text5)) {
     $abc->redirect('../xxxx.php');
     exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($text1)== True && isset($text2)== True)) || (isset($text3)==True xor isset($text4)=True xor isset($text5)==true xor isset($text6)==true)
```